# Telerik Rad Captcha - Validation always returns false - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, captcha, rad-controls

I have tried to use a `Rad Captcha` control in my ASP.NET application. The control will display the images, but I can never get it to validate. No matter what I do it returns false.

I am using the current Telerik tools: `UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2013 SP1`

I have an ASP.NET button, in the click event I have this code here:

```
RadCap.Validate();
Page.Validate();

if (RadCap.IsValid)
{                
    Label1.Text = "Right";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Wrong";
}
```

I also have tried to add a `validation summary` to the web form, and setting the `validation group` to the same name on all the controls. Can some please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a timer that was controlling my ad rotator, if I disabled the time, the Rad Captcha works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of the Telerik controls? According to the following release notes, there was an issue with the captcha validation when it is triggered multiple times: http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-ajax/release-history/q3-2013-sp1-version-2013-3-1114

Comment: I am using that version of Telerik tools